# API data prints to console in node but doesn't display in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

My goal is to do a simple get request and display the data to an HTML page.

So first I set up the request in node.js to test it. With node, the data showed up correctly when I ran it with `console.log(response)`.

The problem comes when I try to display the data to the page. Basically, nothing shows up when I try `document.getElementByID('demo').innerHTML = response;`
I even tried to just use an alert but to no avail.

I am obviously doing something wrong but I am not familiar enough with JavaScript to know.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

//causes error in html. Required for node.
// var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

var HttpClient = function() {
    this.get = function(aUrl, aCallback) {
              var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { 
                if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
                   aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
                }

            anHttpRequest.open( "GET", aUrl, true );            
              anHttpRequest.send( null );
        }
}

var theURL = 'https://XXXXXX..';
var client = new HttpClient();
let thisReply = null;
client.get(theURL, function(response) {
//   var response1 = JSON.parse(response);
    // alert(response1);
    // console.log(response);
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = response;
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you try document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response);

Comment: It should work fine, there should be some problem with your API. I tried it in jsfiddle and it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/dani19/wynd2sut/1/

Comment: @NaldPrabha Yes I have tried that as well but the page still displays nothing.

Comment: Check `Network` tab in browser developer tools to see what you are getting in the response.

Comment: Please check the response, as you see in my above comment the fiddle is working fine.

Comment: @NaldPrabha I just tried that link too and it works with your api link..So strange. I mean I am getting the JSON back with Node and I used PostMan to make a call to my API and it also worked so the API ought to be fine which is why im so confused haha

Comment: @PrerakSola I checked that and I saw a console error that said Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://APILINK' from origin 'http://...' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: Voila. You need to enable CORS on your API server. If you are using node along with express, refer this: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: @PrerakSola Thanks for that suggestion and the link. You guys are awesome! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PrerakSola and @Abdullah Danyal answered the question in the main post comments.
"I checked that and I saw a console error that said Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'APILINK' from origin 'http://...' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

ANSWER: "You need to enable CORS on your API server. If you are using node along with express, refer to : expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is not an issue with the document not finding the element you are looking for, you could try .innerText = response or wrapping your innerHTML elem in some HTML element: `<p>${response}</p>` I would be sure to also log out that element in addition to the api response to be sure you're grabbing the right thing.

Comment: I was curious about your answer so I tried it just to see. Unfortunately it is a cross-origin request issue. The fix for me is to enable cross-site HTTP requests. I found this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) describing what CORS is and following the instructions on this [link](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) solves the issue. Thanks @anna

Comment: Oh nice! I'm glad you found the solution!